# Nx invalid symbol in nx.json

Tags: angular, node-modules, nx-monorepo

I recently installed and migrated my project to nx monorepo. Everything worked fine, after updateing project from git (no changes in this angular project) I cannot serve, build or even "npm i" due to this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Angular\node_modules\nx
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./bin/post-install
npm ERR! D:\Angular\node_modules\nx\src\utils\fileutils.js:26
npm ERR!         throw e;
npm ERR!         ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: InvalidSymbol in D:\Angular\nx.json at 1:1
npm ERR! > 1 | {
npm ERR!     | ^
npm ERR!   2 |   "defaultBase": "master",
npm ERR!   3 |   "namedInputs": {
npm ERR!   4 |     "sharedGlobals": [],
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at parseJson (D:\Angular\node_modules\nx\src\utils\json.js:27:15)
npm ERR!     at readJsonFile (D:\Angular\node_modules\nx\src\utils\fileutils.js:22:37)
npm ERR!     at readNxJson (D:\Angular\node_modules\nx\src\config\nx-json.js:11:66)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Angular\node_modules\nx\src\daemon\client\client.js:322:72)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.9.0
```

My nx.json seems fine, i've checked for invisible characters.

```
{
  "defaultBase": "master",
  "namedInputs": {
    "sharedGlobals": [],
    "default": ["{projectRoot}/**/*", "sharedGlobals"],
    "production": [
      "default",
      "!{projectRoot}/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "!{projectRoot}/**/*.spec.[jt]s",
      "!{projectRoot}/karma.conf.js",
      "!{projectRoot}/.eslintrc.json",
      "!{projectRoot}/eslint.config.js"
    ]
  },
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "inputs": ["production", "^production"],
      "cache": true
    },
    "test": {
      "inputs": ["default", "^production", "{workspaceRoot}/karma.conf.js"],
      "cache": true
    },
    "lint": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintrc.json",
        "{workspaceRoot}/eslint.config.js"
      ],
      "cache": true
    },
    "@nx/eslint:lint": {
      "cache": true,
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintrc.json",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintignore",
        "{workspaceRoot}/eslint.config.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/eslint/plugin",
      "options": {
        "targetName": "lint"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought it might be cache or node modules issues, so i deleted nx cache, node_modules and package-lock.json to reinstall modules, but when i wanted to npm install i got the same error like before when trying to build.

Comment: Check the encoding of the file. Perhaps someone (you or coworker) converted the file to UTF with BOM. In that case, your editor wouldn't catch it, but the parser might might choke on those few first bytes. If that's the case, convert it back to UTF without BOM.